# php combinatoric

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь в php. Нашел такой код:

```
    <?php

function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) { 
        print join(' ', $perms) . "<br>";
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}
print_r(pc_permute(array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0')));

?>
```

помогите пожалуйста допилить чтобы, можно было выставить ограничение например в 3 знака(чтобы примерно так 123 / 567/ 739) и чтобы например  могло сохранить в файл.txt а то комп долго думает временами и памяти мало.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вам эти 3 знака, если получатся просто числа от 100 до 999, которые вы и так сможете ввести?

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить можно вот так.

```php
        $file = fopen("Путь_к_файлу.txt", w);
        fwrite($file, "Текст_который_нужно_записать");
        fclose($file);
```